How do I cycle between multiple buttons?
How to make this code more efficient??
I tried to hard code it by if else but it doesn't work. If I click a button then the previous content of the previous button keeps poping up
const product_img   = document.getElementById("analytics-img");
const border        = document.getElementById("product-box-border");
const delete_prod   = document.getElementById("product-box-border-delete");
const update_prod   = document.getElementById("product-box-border-Update");
const user          = document.getElementById("user");
const view_products = document.getElementById("viewproducts");

// Initially hiding all sections except the analytics image
border.style.display        = 'none';
delete_prod.style.display   = 'none';
update_prod.style.display   = 'none';
user.style.display          = 'none';
view_products.style.display = 'none';

function displaySection(sectionId) {
  // Array of all section IDs
  const sections = [product_img, border, delete_prod, update_prod, user, view_products];

  // Hide all sections
  sections.forEach(section => {
    if (section !== sectionId) {
      section.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });

  // Display the selected section
  sectionId.style.display = 'block';
}

function admin_profile() {
  displaySection(user);
}

function display() {
  displaySection(border);
}

function return_func() {
  displaySection(product_img);
}

function return_func_delete() {
  displaySection(product_img);
}

function update_button() {
  displaySection(update_prod);
}

function viewProducts() {
  displaySection(view_products);
}

Upon click the viewProducts() I do get the required page but the previous page content is still there

Please include the relevant html.

in this kind of case it is better to group the buttons on the html page
